# need popup display of term definition in page contents

Tags: navigation

I have glossary terms in site as glossary type content. Client now wants to have each instance of each term linked to the term explanation, to popup when user hovers over term.

Suggestions? Modules? Magic?

Comment: Are you using D6 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Popups API (Ajax Dialogs)](http://drupal.org/project/popups) module.